# Exporting Chinese characters from Excel to R

Tags: r, csv, character-encoding

I have a file in Excel which has a column with Chinese simplified characters. When I open it in R from the corresponding CSV file I only get ?'s.

I'm afraid the problem is when exporting from Excel to CSV because when I open the CSV file on a text editor I also get ?'s.

How can I get around this?

Comment: Could you prepare a reproducible example?

Comment: In general if you can export your data as UTF-8 And handle it everywhere as UTF-8 then you will have few problems.
Unfortunately there are several Chinese specific encodings, such as BIG-5 which are only supported by some applications and not others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to secure your Chinese/Unicode characters is to read file from `.xlsx`:

```
library(readxl)
read_xlsx("yourfilepath.xlsx", col_types = "text")
```

If your file is too big to read from `.xlsx`, then the best way is to open Excel and split manually into multiple files.
(My experience with a laptop with 8GB RAM is to split files into 250,000 rows x 106 columns.)

If you need to read from `.csv`, your all windows settings/localization needs to be the same as your file, but even that does not guarantee the integrity of all your Unicode characters (eg. emojis).

(If you also need `.csv` for something else, then you can use the `R` function `write.csv` after you read data from `.xlsx` into `R`.)